# MS Access query criteria showing parameter box

Tags: ms-access

I am making a query that feeds information into a report in MS Access. I have a search function that uses  `"*" & [Form]![FormName]![ComboBox] & "*"` in one of the fields and is linked to a search box - this all works fine. However, I also have a button that opens the complete report - every time I click this button it asks for the parameter of the search box. I know this is happening because that's the criteria the query is based on. I'm just wondering if there is a way to get Access to ignore this criteria if the "Open Complete Report" button is pressed?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is decouple this report from the `FormName` form.

To do that, remove the `"*" & [Form]![FormName]![ComboBox] & "*"` condition from your query, and then pass a WHERE clause when you open the report using [DoCmd.OpenReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openreport).

For your form with the combobox, it would look something like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "SomeReport", acViewNormal, , "SomeField = " & "*" & [ComboBox] & "*"
```

And for your "Open Complete Report" button, it would simply be

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "SomeReport", acViewNormal
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works. thanks very much. I figured I may have to do something akin to this but didnt quite know how to make it work.